# What are the existing open source tools to develop on-premise organizational app store on linux?

Tags: cluster, deployment

We have a Linux cluster in our organization and my data science team is developing a number of ML projects to be utilized by teams across the organization. To enable the teams to access the ML models, the idea is to create apps and add them to an app store. So that any of the internal teams, can register to use the app and use it for their project.

Are there existing open-source tools to achieve this objective?

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux distros don't have "app stores" - this is a term invented by Apple for its mobiles phones.

What Linux distros employ are repositories where you can publish your packages and then install them using standard distro tools, `dnf` for RPM based distros and `apt` for DPKG based distros.

- DPKG manual: [official](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/SetupWithReprepro) [another](https://medium.com/sqooba/create-your-own-custom-and-authenticated-apt-repository-1e4a4cf0b864)
- RPM manuals: [official](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/apache-yum-dnf-repo) [another](https://medium.com/@daniel.s.holdsworth/creating-your-own-local-yum-repository-f2e4dc333851)

For other distros Google for "DistroName create repository"